# filtering nested JSON underscore

Tags: jquery, json, underscore.js

This is the jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/sal1681/2043fumn/

When I execute the code, it returns one subitem for market ATL, in actuality it should not return anything for subitem ATL since I am filtering by flag which is set to false.

Here is the code

```
var json = JSON.parse('[
  {
    "market": "Atl",
    "subItem": [
      {
        "comment_id": "1",
        "flag": false,
        "user_id": "32509"
      },
      {
        "comment_id": "2",
        "flag": false,
        "user_id": "32510"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "market": "Chicago",
    "subItem": [
      {
        "comment_id": "3",
        "flag": true,
        "user_id": "32501"
      },
      {
        "comment_id": "4",
        "flag": false,
        "user_id": "32502"
      }
    ]
  }
]');

for(var i=0; i<json.length; i++) {
    json[i].subItem = _.without(json[i].subItem, _.findWhere(json[i].subItem, {flag: false}));
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(json, 0, 8));
```

Comment: There is one item which is true in `Atl`

Comment: I just changed it to false

Comment: Here is the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sal1681/2043fumn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is that `findWhere` only returns the *first* value that matches, not a list of the matching values.

A better option is probably to use the `filter` function.

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
  json[i].subItem = _.filter(json[i].subItem, function(subItem) {
    return subItem.flag;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a variant of the previous answer with `Arrray.forEach` and `Array.filter` (if you're allowed to use it):

```
json.forEach(function(item) {
  item.subItem = item.subItem.filter(function(subItem) {
    return subItem.flag;
  });
});
```